# avoid button_to action with javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart, cart, button-to

I am making a shopping cart and the user can only add products to the cart when signed in.

I created some JavaScript for when the user clicks the button "Add to cart", it evaluates if someone is signed in and displays a message, but I need to stop the button action because cause a problem for a render action. 
Thanks. Here is my code

```
<%=button_to 'Add to cart',line_items_path(:product_id => product.id),:onclick=>"javascript:is_user()"%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <%= button_to 'Add to cart',line_items_path(:product_id => product.id) %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'Login to add to cart', '' %>
<% end %>
```